# Why is wordpress function returning values outside of my variable

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have a function in the functions.php file in my wordpress theme folder. This function creates a link to a php file where you can download the ics file for selected wordpress post in the frontend.

```
 function ics_maker() {
    $ics_link = "<a href='https://intranet.local/wp/icsmaker.php?eventname=".the_title()."&eventort=".the_field('eventort')."&eventstart=".the_field('eventstart')."&eventende=".the_field('eventende')."&eventext=".get_the_content()."'>Download</a>";
    return $ics_link;
}
add_shortcode( 'shortcode_icsmaker', 'ics_maker');
```

If I add this shortcode with

```
[shortcode_icsmaker]
```

I'm getting this:

```
TitleofICSAddressOfICS24.03.2022 13:0024.03.2022 17:00 Download
```

The download link is a working link but have empty vars inside href excepct *eventext*:

```
https://intranet.local/wp/icsmaker.php?eventname=&eventort=&eventstart=&eventende=&eventext=Lorem%20123
```

It seems like the_title(), the_field("eventort"),... return themselves outside of the $ics_link variable, but why?

Comment: [the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) and [the_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) will echo the value to the screen if you don't tell it not to. For `the_title`, you need to pass `false` as the third parameter. For `the_field`, you would use `get_field()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the WordPress function reference (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/):

> `the_title( string $before = '', string $after = '', bool $echo = true )`
>
> Display or retrieve the current post title with optional markup.

By default it echoes the title. You need to either explicitly ask for returning the title instead: `the_title('', '', false)` or use the `get_the_title()` method, just like you did with `get_the_content()`.

Instead of ACF's `the_field()`, you have the `get_field()` function, which returns the field value instead of echoing it (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/).

Comment: the_title('', '', false) worked for me. Thank you very much!